# Migrating from Wordpress.com to Ghost - What SEO considerations do I need to make?

Tags: seo, wordpress, ghost-blog

This question here already answers a lot of questions:

[Migrating from a wordpress.com to wordpress.org blog without harming SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/migrating-from-a-wordpress-com-to-wordpress-org-blog-without-harming-seo)

However - I guess I'm asking the same question for a generic 'other' blogging platform.

I'd likely follow the guide here: http://bijoor.me/2016/08/06/migrating-from-wordpress-to-ghost/

Does the platform differences matter - or does following the guide more or less apply?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like both guides you've provided seem to cover most what you would have to do when migrating a site from one CMS to another.

Platform differences do not matter when it comes to SEO- it's all how you handle your traffic via redirects/etc, and what you do with your content. which is covered in both of the guides you supplied.

Comment: Platform differences do not **usually** matter to SEO.   However, some platforms are not easily crawled by Google, especially some newer single page application frameworks.   Some platforms do stupid SEO things like put session ids in URLs.  Some platforms don't support canonical tags, sitemaps, or other features that are commonly used to improve SEO.

Comment: >it's all how you handle your traffic via redirects/etc